# How to use vertices of a curve as keyframes for posing an armature?

Tags: animation, armature, parent

I have generated a curve in geometry nodes and I want to use each of its vertices as a keyframe for a object.

I have tried to animate the object along the curve using 'follow path' constraint. But it doesn't give me a result with constant time per segment.

I have also tried simulating the object within geometry nodes itself to get the desired dynamic result. But then its not possible to use the exported simulation as an Alembic to be parented to an armature in pose mode, which is my end goal.

How do I animate a bone in an armature to the vertices of this curve?

[image]

Comment: you should further explain what you mean with "But it doesn't give me a dynamic result by following the spacing between each vertex. " how dynamic should it be? what's the formula you wanna use there? But you know that you cannot set keyframes with GN do you? So honestly, if you really wanna set keyframes, you should think about using animation nodes, which can handle that by expressions/python nodes. GN cannot set keyframes itself as it is now.

Comment: Hi, @Chris..   I read this as:  'constant time per segment' rather than 'constant time per length' ... Sampada:  if this is correct, could you edit something to that effect into your question, to avoid any doubt?

Comment: hi @RobinBetts. Yes that's what i meant. i'm not that well-versed in the technical terms so i wasn't aware of phrasing it as 'constant time per segment'. thanks

Answer (score 1):

My understanding: you have a GN curve; you want a bone to acquire the position of one control in the curve; each frame, you want this bone to acquire the position of the next control in the curve.

[image]

Make a mesh object (doesn't matter what, we're not using its base geo.)  Instance your curve into it with geometry nodes.  Instance a vertex at a control point on the curve, determined by comparing the current frame to the index of the curve.  Realize instances to allow the bone to use a shrinkwrap constraint to acquire the position of the nearest vertex of this mesh object.

Because you didn't specify, and for the sake of simplicity-- you want to understand things in their smallest, simplest parts before moving on-- this is not cyclic.  When the frame count gets high and it runs out of controls, the bone goes to its rest pose.

Comment: thanks! this method is working